# Finding the cone angle from a bunch of vectors that lie on the cone

Tags: geometry

I have the 3d coordinates of some points lying on a cone (describing a hyperbola in my case), and also a list of vectors lying on the cone, starting at these points. Can I use them to figure out the cone angle?

Is this even a well-defined problem, i.e., is there sufficient information?

Comment: Yes, I was hasty. I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the point-vector pairs defines a line that lies on the cone. Its vertex is the common intersection point of all of these lines. From the lines you can generate a system of linear equations the solution to which is the cone’s vertex. For real-world noisy data, this system will most likely be inconsistent, so you’ll have to use an estimation algorithm such as [DLT with total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation).

All of these lines make the same angle with the cone’s axis $\mathbf v$. If you normalize the direction vectors $\mathbf d_i$, you can then generate another system of linear equations of the form $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf d_i=c$, where $c$ is the unknown cosine of the common angle times the length of $\mathbf v$. As with the vertex, this system is very likely to be inconsistent in the presence of noisy real-world data, so you will need to resort to an estimate here, too.

Observe that the fact that your points lie on a hyperbola doesn’t really come into play, although you might be able to use the fact that all of the points are coplanar to get a better estimate of the vertex and axis.

Comment: @N.Bach Yep. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Let me recapitulate. A cone is specified by three parameter -- the axis (unit vector $\hat v$, and the cone angle $\alpha$. I first use the vectors to estimate the position of the tip of the cone. Then, I consider all possible unit vectors originating from that point (the 2-sphere), and then do some least-squares minimisation to find the unit vector as well as the cone angle. Is that it?

Comment: And provided I have more than three vectors on the cone, that should be enough to fix the three parameters.

Comment: @ap21 You also need the cone’s vertex/apex/tip. It also appears that you’re assuming a right circular cone. That aside, it looks like you’ve understood the process I described. Least-squares might not give the best estimate, but it’s fairly simple to implement.